# WPF binding weirdness

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've used binding many times but this caught me by surprise. 
In resources of TabControl I have  defined:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ScreenViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:converter x:Key="conv"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <di:DisplayView Ime="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource conv}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource conv}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>      
</DataTemplate>
```

with converter defined as :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value;
}
```

just to debug binding process.

di:DisplayView has Ime dependency property of type string and 
local:ScreenViewModel class with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented has Name property which I would like to bind to.

Now, the problem with this code is that when I put breakpoint in Convert method of "conv" I see breakpoint is hit twice. First there is predefined string value set in Name and the next time there is empty string. Even if I remove TextBlock binding i still get empty string as value but if I remove di:DisplayView then everything works fine.

I should mention that  is UserControl defined in another namespace as ClassLibrary.

Strange behaviour of WPF, isn't it?

Comment: We cannot really reproduce your problem without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you check with a tool like [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) whether the DisplayView and TextBlock elements have different values for DataContext?

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of the DisplayView class. Make sure that DisplayView does not explicitly set its DataContext, e.g. to some other ScreenViewModel instance.

Comment: I have found the soulution. Although no error is displayed there was a problem in type of DependencyProperty Ime. Thank you for responses.